# How to Fix “Error Establishing a Database Connection” in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress website and It's working perfectly but sometimes more than 3-4 times in a day it's going down and display error "Error Establishing a Database Connection".

I am using AWS server. Every time I have open the putty and rebooting the server.

Below command, I am using on putty

```
sudo -i
sudo reboot
```

Some time login on AWS then `Action->instance state->Reboot` and then it's working.

Sometimes "The connection has timed out".

Would you help me out what is the issue with AWS server? Currently, my plane is micro.

Comment: A few days ago there was an attack on my website.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and despite trying the suggestions, it didn't work.
Finally did two changes and it worked-

1- used My sql 5.6.40 version
2- Also added All traffic to outbound rule in the EC2 Security group (WebDMZ).

Comment: Hey, you can use formattings in your answers, would be nice if you structure your one a little by using bullet points or numbering

Comment: @Nazneen, I don't know why I was getting that error. Now I am using a large server. Now I am not getting that issue. but this is not a correct solution for me.